# SQL how to exclude data

Tags: sql

[image]

How to make a query to exclude id for this scenario:

1. Contains failed status
2. Contains failed status, even it has 1 or more success status
3. Contains pending status

Based on the image, it should only choose B001 and E001

I prepare query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE a 
WHERE a.Content = 'Submit' 
  AND a.Status = 'S' 
  AND a.Status NOT IN ('F', 'P')
```

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. all its rows/columns.)

Comment: Also please specify what DBMS you are using: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ...

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to check other rows content for your condition, you need a sub-query.

Here I use `NOT EXISTS` clause. It checks that fpr crrent row there are now rows with same ID, but status `F` or `P`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE a 
WHERE a.Content = 'Submit' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE a1
    WHERE a1.ID = a.ID
    AND a.Status IN ('F', 'P')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use window functions! No need for aggregation, self-joining or subqueries:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        max(case when status in ('F', 'P') then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) has_f_or_p
    from mytable t
) t
where has_f_or_p = 0
```

This scans the table only once, and hence is more efficient than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregated data to determine if the status is only 'S' over multiple rows. You cannot do this with just equality or inequality operators.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    ID varchar(4),
    Content varchar(10),
    Status varchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO data (ID, Content, Status)
VALUES
('A001', 'Process', 'S'),    ('A001', 'Verify', 'F'),    ('B001', 'Process', 'S'),
('C001', 'Process', 'P'),    ('D001', 'Submit', 'P'),    ('D001', 'Process', 'S'),
('E001', 'Process', 'S'),    ('E001', 'Verify', 'S'),    ('E001', 'Submit', 'S');


select
    *
from data
where id in (
  select id
  from data
  group by id
  having min(status) = max(status) and max(status) = 'S'
  )

| id   | content | status |
|:---  |:--------|:-------|
| B001 | Process | S      |
| E001 | Process | S      |
| E001 | Verify  | S      |
| E001 | Submit  | S      |
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EAAPF3oU)

alternate use an inner join:

```
select
    *
from data
inner join (
  select id
  from data
  group by id
  having min(status) = max(status) and max(status) = 'S'
  ) as sq on data.id = sq.id
```

NB: It is never a good idea to use an image of your data, just paste it as a simple text table.